# C++: When is method redefinition preferred over virtual method override?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding, static-binding

Do virtual methods bind statically when objects are not created dynamically?

If virtual methods have the best of both worlds (static *and* dynamic binding when needed), what is the point of having non-virtual methods? In what cases would one prefer their use over virtual ones?

For better explanations I included a simple class hierarchy.

**Base Class:**

```
Class Base
{
/*
 Member data, constructors and destructors
*/
public:
  void my_redefined_func();
  virtual void my_overriden_func();
};
```

**Derived Class:**

```
Derived : public Base
{
/*
 Member data, constructors and destructors
*/
public:
  void my_redefined_func();
  virtual void my_overriden_func() override;
};
```

Comment: virtual _functions_ (C++ doesn't have "methods") often carry a runtime overhead.  They are not always as efficient as non-virtual functions.

Comment: @DrewDormann They don't though with static dispatching, the vtable addition might be memory overhead though.

Comment: `Base* b = new Derived(); b->my_redefined_func();` will call the Base member function, not the Derived member function.  Sometimes that is what is wanted.  Other times, it is a problem.

Comment: Is this overhead present when there's no dynamic data allocation (related to the first question)? Are the viertual functions statically bound in this case?

Comment: A compiler's optimizer can use the *as if* rule to statically bind the virtual member function.  The compiler is not required to do so.  The compiler is required to do dynamic dispatch, but the *as if* rule gives it the leeway to optimize the call where possible.

Comment: Creating the object dynamically doesn't matter. `Derived d; Base* b = &d;` does the same thing, and raises the same issues. The only difference is that `d` will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, so `delete b;` would be wrong.